# OpenCV CreateVideoWriter() problems

Tags: python, opencv, video

So I'm trying to write some motion detection code for my raspberry pi
I'm running debian and opencv 2.3.1 with python 2.7 
I'm getting the following error

cv2.error: Array should be CvMat or IplImage

```
def initRecorder(self): #Create the recorder
    codec = cv.CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G') #('W', 'M', 'V', '2')
    self.writer=cv.CreateVideoWriter(datetime.now().strftime("%b-%d_%H:%M:%S")+".wmv", codec, 5, cv.GetSize(self.frame), 1)
    self.font = cv.InitFont(cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 1, 0, 2, 8) #Creates a font
```

Comment: Change `cv.GetSize(self.frame)` to `(640,480)` and see the error is there.

Comment: thanks, I actually discovered that OpenCv doesn't detect the camera module as a camera so self.frame was just None